# POST data is not being passed to other view controller

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am running into a small problem with my project. I am new to iOS development, and I am running into a slight problem trying to pass some data that I have pulled out of a response body in JSON format. I am able to print out the correct data from the server right after I assign it to a variable in the class, but once I prepare and perform a segue, it doesn't seem to pass over. Here is my first viewController:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftyJSON

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var emailAddress: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var userPassword: UITextField!
    var returned_email: String!
    var returned_pass: String!
    var current_exp: Int!
    var needed_exp: Int!

    @IBAction func getUserDataBtn(_ sender: Any) {
        if emailAddress.text != "" && userPassword.text != ""
        {
            let session = URLSession.shared
            let parameters = ["nameValuePairs":["username": emailAddress.text, "password": userPassword.text]]
            guard let myURL = URL(string: "<protected url>") else {return}
            var request = URLRequest(url: myURL, cachePolicy: URLRequest.CachePolicy.useProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 300.0)

            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            guard let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: []) else {return}
            request.httpBody = httpBody
            request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

            session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
                if let myData = data{
                    do{
                        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: myData, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String:Any]
                        self.returned_email = json["username"] as! String
                        self.returned_pass = json["password"] as! String
                        self.current_exp = json["curr_exp"] as! Int
                        self.needed_exp = json["needed_exp"] as! Int
                    }
                    catch{
                        print(error)
                    }
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "GetUserDataSegue", sender: self)
                }
            }).resume()
        }
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
        if(segue.identifier == "GetUserDataSegue"){
            guard let viewController = segue.destination as? UserDataController else {return}
            viewController.myUN = returned_email
            viewController.myPW = returned_pass
            viewController.myCurrExp = current_exp
            viewController.myNeedExp = needed_exp
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        }
}
```

Here is my other viewcontroller:

```
import UIKit

class UserDataController: UIViewController {
    var myUN: String!
    var myPW: String!
    var myCurrExp: Int!
    var myNeedExp: Int!

    @IBOutlet weak var password: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var username: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var current_exp: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var needed_exp: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        username.text = myUN
        password.text = myPW
        current_exp.text = String(describing: myCurrExp)
        needed_exp.text = String(describing: myNeedExp)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}
```

What I am trying to accomplish with this test project is to have a person enter in their username and password, hit "get user data" button, be taken to the second viewcontroller with all of their information displayed in the provided labels. I am able to get the correct data from the database on the server, and I am able to receive it and save it to the local variables in the first viewcontroller. Any help would be appreciated! I am using Swift 4 and Xcode 9, if that has any impact on answers.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: What happens when you step through `prepare(for segue: sender:)`? Is `viewController` valid? Do its properties get set?

Comment: @Caleb The view controller is valid, but my local variables I am passing are nil. I am not sure how to get the information from the json into my local variables (or just call my segue with access to my json data). Any suggestions?

Comment: @Caleb After doing some printing to my console inside the prepare function, I see that my viewcontroller is getting all of the properties set. Not sure why it's not working in the UserDataController.swift

Comment: Once I started running break points in my code, I found out that once I leave the closure of the session, my class variables are not stored any more. I'm not sure what is causing that to happen

Answer (score 1):

> Once I started running break points in my code, I found out that once I leave the closure of the session, my class variables are not stored any more. I'm not sure what is causing that to happen

That sounds a lot like a case of mistaken identity, i.e. you somehow have two instances of `ViewController`, and the one initiating the segue isn't the one that's the `source` view controller in the segue. Since you're already passing `self` for the `sender` parameter in your call to `performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)`, check to see if `sender == self` in `prepare(for:sender:)`.

Comment: Ok, so after fighting with the code and doing breakpoints everywhere, I have found out the my `prepare(for segue: sender:)` function is called before I enter my session. Is there any way to stop the prepare until after I am done with the session?

Answer (score 0):

After doing some more research on how to get my dataTask to run before my prepare was started, I found this little thing that helped me get it working:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.returned_email = json["username"] as! String
                        self.returned_pass = json["password"] as! String
                        self.current_exp = json["curr_exp"] as! Int
                        self.needed_exp = json["needed_exp"] as! Int
                        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "GetUserDataSegue", sender: self)
                    }
```

By wrapping the DispatchQueue.main.async around the setting of my class variables, and then calling the performSegue, I was able to have prepare get called after the dataTask, and allowing my class variables to be sent to the second view.

Another thing that helped me was to change where my segue would happen. Instead of having it come from the button, I had it come from the viewcontroller, and perform that segue when the button was clicked and my data was returned and set from the server.

Thank you to all for your help, it has helped me understand this topic a lot more!